# VB The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl

I have a Visual Basic client program that gets a "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." exception when doing a `GetRequestStream` on an instance of `HttpWebRequest`.  This program used to work when the server allowed protocols were "SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3" and the client program did not set the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` property at all

The Server has been changed to allow "SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3".  Originally the program did not set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`.  After the server was changed I got the above exception so I added

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

but still get the exception above.

Using VB.NET, VS2013 and targeting the 4.5 framework which I see is required for TLS 1.2.

The exception status is

> SecureChannelFailure {10}
>   System.Net.WebExceptionStatus

I saw a post about logging and turned on verbose trace and I can see the handshaking with the certificate.  Below is the tail portion of the trace where it fails:

> System.Net Information: 0 : [6792] SecureChannel#54616604 -
>   Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [6792] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package =
>   Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc 
>   = System.Net.SecureCredential)
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [6792]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(credential =
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context 
>   = 1bb58fc0:1cff780, targetName = paygate-dev1.eaglesoa.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory,
>   InitManualCredValidation)
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [6792]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=173,
>   returned code=ContinueNeeded).
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [6792]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(credential =
>   System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 1bb58fc0:1cff780,
>   targetName = paygate-dev1.eaglesoa.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect,
>   SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory,
>   InitManualCredValidation)
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [6792]
>   InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0,
>   returned code=IllegalMessage).
>
> **System.Net Error: 0 : [6792] Exception in HttpWebRequest#63403007:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..**
>
> **System.Net Error: 0 : [6792] Exception in HttpWebRequest#63403007::EndGetRequestStream - The request was
>   aborted: Could  not create SSL/TLS secure channel..**

Below is a small portion of the client program:  I also tried with tls and ssl3 in the `SecurityProtocol` list, `Expect100Continue` `True` and `False` (saw this on other posts), `AutoRedirect` `True` and `False`.  The exception occurs on the last statement shown `loWebRequest.GetRequestStream()`.  The same certificate is being used as before when it worked.  If the server changes its allowed protocols back to the original value (see them above) it works fine. I also added the certificate to the certificate store.  Any idea on what I need to do on the client?

```
Dim loDataToSend As System.IO.Stream
Dim loWebRequest As HttpWebRequest

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.tls or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True

loWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(lsSystemURL), HttpWebRequest)

With loWebRequest
    .Method = "POST"
    .ClientCertificates = lcCertificates
    .Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    .UseDefaultCredentials = False
    .ContentLength = lsRequest.Length
    .KeepAlive = False
    .AllowAutoRedirect = True
    .Timeout = 100000
End With

loDataToSend = loWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```